# want to change the state through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Actually as the button press, I want to call the function and through this I want to update some Data on db.

**Here is my Code :**

```
echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' id='click' onclick='loadDoc()'>Approve</button>"; 
// as the button is click loadDoc() is call
```

**`loadDoc()` code is here :**

```
function loadDoc() 
{
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
     xhttp.open('GET', 'updatebox.php', true);
     xhttp.send();
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'hello';
}
```

**Here is my `updatebox.php` :**

```
<?php
   include_once("Order.php");
   include("connection.php");
   $query="UPDATE orders
   SET status='cooking'
     WHERE order_id='this.order_id'";
   $filter_Result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

  // here is the problem i just want to update some data into my table and   after that i want to remove the button 

?>
```

[image: first pic]

[image: second pic]

Comment: You want to hide submit button on ajax success? am i right?

Comment: It looks like you need an introductory SQL tutorial. Learn about UPDATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: @Quentin the sql query is only for the testing purpose

Comment: @Apb actually i want to update my db after button click and after updation i want to update my page also

Comment: @DhruvTyagi — Asking about how to update a database and then showing a SELECT statement in your code isn't very helpful. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @Quentin sorry it's my mistake, actually i will explain my whole motive......
Actually on my page i created a box, in which they hold the particular row data as the user click on the box a modal is appear and o the Modal i create a button as a user click on the button the status of the box is changes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the data in your table you have to use `update` query, take a look to **[SQL Update](http://sql.sh/cours/update)**. to check if the db is updated use condition like example below :

```
if (mysqli_query($connection,$query)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Then to hide the button you could  use `get()` request instead :

```
$.get('updatebox.php',{},function(){
     $('click').hide();
})
```

OR with `XMLHttpRequest` success callback :

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("click").style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: after query send how can i know my db is updated or not?

Comment: I have some More question please help me.....
1) actually i used the object to populate the box and modal and after button click i have to change the status of a particular id in which the user is click....
my question how can i fetch the id from the object and how can i used into the SQL query

2) after all the update my webpage content is not automatically refresh...

Comment: Hi, i want to help but you have to add more detail in the OP like code you're using to populate modal .. the object ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114526/discussion-between-dhruv-tyagi-and-zakaria-acharki).